# Angular EventEmitter get data

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I just started with learning Angular, but I ran into a problem that I have been trying to work out for the last couple hours. I have a parent child relation between 2 components. Now I want to share a `boolean` variable from my master to a child. The child should display a text when its true and if it is false, show a different text. Here is the @Output code:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Offer} from "../../../models/offer";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview2',
  templateUrl: './overview2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview2.component.css']
})
export class Overview2Component implements OnInit {

  public offers: Offer[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      this.addRandomOffer();
    }
  }

  public addRandomOffer(): void {
    let offer = Offer.createRandomOffer();
    this.offers.push(offer);
  }

  public highlightClickedRow(offer :Offer) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.offers.length; i++) {
      if (this.offers[i] != offer) {
        this.offers[i].rowClicked = false;
      }
      else {
        this.offers[i].rowClicked = true;
        this.selected.emit(true);
      }
    }
  }

  @Output('update')
  selected: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

}
```

Then in my HTML of the parent, I have the following:

```
<div>
  <app-detail2 [offerSelected]="selected"></app-detail2>
</div>
```

In the TypeScript of the child, I collect the @Output as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail2',
  templateUrl: './detail2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail2.component.css']
})
export class Detail2Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() offerSelected: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Then in the child HTML I want to use the boolean to decide to show a label using the following code:

```
<div *ngIf="offerSelected.prototype then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<br>
{{offerSelected.prototype}}
<ng-template #thenBlock><label  id="lblSomethingSelected">Something has been selected yet</label></ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock><label  id="lblNothingSelected">Nothing has been selected yet</label></ng-template>
```

But the problem I am having is that `offerSelected` is always `false`. Now I think its because `offerSelected` is of the type `EventEmitter<boolean>` and not a real `boolean`. But how can I use it like I want to? Please let me know!

Comment: OfferSelected on the child should simply be of type: Boolean. That input receives the true/false value from your output. EventEmitter is only for Output. After that, your HTML then just needs to use *ngIf="offerSelected" to determine visibility

Comment: `Error: src/app/components/offers/overview2/overview2.component.html:17:19 - error TS2322: Type 'EventEmitter<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, if you have a parent-child relationship, you don't need an event emitter to pass data from the parent to the child. Just set "selected" as a boolean property on the parent. When you change that property, the child will receive the new value.

Comment: So I dont need the @input and @output? How do they share information then with the code I have? Or do I need to add something else?

Comment: No. You would need them for the inverse, to pass data from the child to the parent.

Comment: I mean more like a master-detail!!! So I still need them?

Comment: Can we say "master" now? :) But yes, I get you. No, you don't need them to go from parent to child, only child to parent.

Comment: But how do I declare the variable in the child then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237297/discussion-between-brandon-and-a-vreeswijk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to capture the discussion in an answer...

When you have a parent-child relationship between components and are passing data from the parent to the child, you don't need an EventEmitter. You only need to set a property on the parent, and then specify an `@Input` to receive the value in the child.

```
// parent.component.ts

selected: boolean;

// child.component.ts

@Input()
offerSelected: boolean;
```

With that change, the HTML in the child can be:

```
<div *ngIf="offerSelected then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>

<ng-template #thenBlock>
  <label id="lblSomethingSelected">Something has been selected</label>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <label id="lblNothingSelected">Nothing has been selected yet</label>
</ng-template>
```

If you're sending data from the child to the parent, then you need an EventEmitter.